# Avoiding repeating lines in makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I've looked at a lot of different sites to try and find a solution, but I couldn't find any that I understood that didn't include a bunch of other symbols and terms I was unfamiliar with.

I have a makefile that goes along the lines of:

```
all: x1 x2 x3 x4...x(y)

x1: x1.o static1.o static2.o
    gcc -o x1 x1.o static1.o static2.o
x2: x2.o static1.o static2.o
    gcc -o x2 x2.o static1.o static2.o
...
x(y); x(y).o static1.o static2.o
    gcc -o x(y) x(y).o static1.o static2.o

x1.o: x1.c sample1.h sample2.h sample3.h
    gcc -c x1.c

x2.o: x2.c sample1.h sample2.h sample3.h
    gcc -c x2.c
...
x(y).o: x(y).c sample1.h sample2.h sample3.h
    gcc -c x(y).c

static1.o: sample1.c sample1.h sample2.h sample3.h
    gcc -c sample1.c sample2.h

static2.o: sample3.c sample3.h
    gcc -c sample3.c

clean:
    @rm -f *o x1 x2 x3... x(y)
```

y is used as a variable, not as part of the actual name.

How can I reduce this all into just a few lines with something like `x%.o`?

Comment: Do you want to do it without using any symbols and terms you are unfamiliar with?

Comment: @WilliamPursell I'm okay with symbols if you explain what they represent

Comment: How about if we point to the documentation, rather than us explaining it again here?  https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html  See, for example, the second index: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Name-Index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using GNU make, you can use a [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html#Static-Usage). This lets you use the character `%` in the target of a rule, and the rule applies to all target names where the `%` is replaced by any string of characters. If `%` appears in a dependency, it's replaced by that same string.

```
x%: x%.o static1.o static2.o
    gcc -o $@ $*.o static1.o static2.o

x%.o: x%.c sample1.h sample2.h sample3.h
    gcc -c $*.c
```

This mechanism doesn't let you enumerate all the targets for `all`. For this, you need something more complex: list the `.c` files, and declare the corresponding targets as dependencies of `all`. With GNU make, you can do this with the [`wildcard` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html#index-wildcard_002c-function) to list the files and then functions such as [`basename`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html#index-file-name_002c-basename-of) and [`addsuffix`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html#index-file-name-suffix_002c-adding) or [`patsubst`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html#index-patsubst-1) or its abbreviated form to transform the file names.

```
all: $(patsubst %.c,%,$(wildcard x*.c))
```

Note that I assume that the part after `x` can be an arbitrary string, not just an integer within a certain range. I think it's doable to insist on an integer with GNU make, but it would be a lot harder.